# Spring session scoped bean retains state after spring security login

Tags: java, spring

I have a session scoped spring bean declared like

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserSessionData {...}
```

which is Autowired in a bean annotated with @ControllerAdvice

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"package.one", "package.two"})
```

public class GlobalControllerAdvice {...}

I have noticed that when there is a successful login and a successful logout, via spring security xml configuration, then at the next login, the UserSessionData bean keeps its fields from the previous login.

In detail, the login handler declared as

```
authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
```

in the spring security config, has the UserSessionData autowired and when its onAuthenticationSuccess method is called, the bean has the previous state.

I have verified that on logout the @PreDestroy method is called.